# CUDA optimization for a vector tensor product using a custom kernel or CUBLAS

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I have two vectors `a` and `b`. Each vector contains the coordinates of a 3d points `x`, `y`, `z` `vector3f`.

```
struct Vector3f
{ 
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
```

vector `a`  has a size of `n = 5000` points and vector `b` has a size of `m = 4000`. I need to do a tensor vector product between them like on the right side of the picture. the resulted vector should have a length size of `5000 * 4000` and contain float point where results are stored at `c`.
[image]

```
__global__ void tensor3dProdcutClassic(const int n, const int m, const Vector3f *a, const Vector3f *b, float *c) {
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    // int j = blockIdy.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    //check if  the idx is out of range
    if (i < n) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            int idx = j + m * i;
            c[idx] = a[i].x * b[j].x + a[i].y * b[j].y + a[i].z * b[j].z;
        } 
    }
} 

dim3 blockSize(32, 1, 1);
dim3 gridSize((n + blockSize.x - 1) / blockSize.x, 1, 1);

tensor3dProdcutClassic<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(n, m, x, y, out);
```

I get high execution time on Volta arch which is a lot.
My question is how can I optimize the kernel to reduce time which is mainly because of the **for loop** inside the kernel. I know here that all global reads and writes are not coalesced.

Comment: If you want to achieve high performance, then using array of structure is a very bad idea, especially on GPUs based on the SIMT model. Note to mention that alignment will likely be an issue due to the number of field which is not divisible by a power of two.

Comment: thank you Richard,  you are right. I have changed the Vector3f to typedef float  Point3d[3]; but I still get high compuation time

Comment: The problem is not the structure itself, but the memory layout. While an array of 3 float might be better regarding possible padding or not, it still causes inefficient interleaved reads. I was thinking about having 3 plain big arrays (x + y + z).

Comment: Agree,  defining 3 plain arrays or storing them in a matrix with row-major order gives better perf and gives effiecnt interleaved reads. I will modify the code. However, the major problem is the kernel implementation which is not optimized and because of this, it is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the kernel move through both `a` and `b` simultaneously, like this:

```
__global__ void tensor3dProdcutClassic(const int n, const int m, const Vector3f *a, const Vector3f *b, float *c)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdy.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (i < n && j < m)
    {
        int idx = j + m * i;
        c[idx] = a[i].x * b[j].x + a[i].y * b[j].y + a[i].z * b[j].z;
    }
}

dim3 blockSize(32, 32);
dim3 gridSize((int)ceil(n / 32.0), (int)ceil(m / 32.0));

tensor3dProdcutClassic<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(n, m, x, y, out);
```

**Update**
I tried to modify the code to use a single array with and without shared memory, the code without shared memory with always faster 3 or 4 times.

With shared memory:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 32
void tensor3dProdcut(const int n, const int m, const float* a, const float* b, float* c)
{
    float* d_a;
    size_t size = (uint64_t)n * 3 * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float* d_b;
    size = (uint64_t)m * 3 * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float* d_c;
    size = (uint64_t)n * m * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc(&d_c, size);
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid((int)ceil((double)n / BLOCK_SIZE), (int)ceil((double)m / BLOCK_SIZE));
    tensor3dProdcutKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c, n, m);
    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
}

__global__ void tensor3dProdcutKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, int n, int m)
{
    int i, blockRow, blockCol, row, col;
    float Cvalue;
    blockRow = blockIdx.x;
    blockCol = blockIdx.y;
    row = threadIdx.x;
    col = threadIdx.y;
    if (blockRow * BLOCK_SIZE + row >= n || blockCol * BLOCK_SIZE + col >= m)
        return;
    __shared__ double as[BLOCK_SIZE][3];
    __shared__ double bs[BLOCK_SIZE][3];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        as[row][i] = a[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockRow + row) * 3 + i];
        bs[col][i] = b[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockCol + col) * 3 + i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    Cvalue = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Cvalue += as[row][i] * bs[col][i];
    c[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockRow + row) * m + BLOCK_SIZE * blockCol + col] = Cvalue;
}
```

Without shared memory:

```
__global__ void tensor3dProdcutKernel(float* a, float* b, float* c, int n, int m)
{
    int i, blockRow, blockCol, row, col;
    float Cvalue;
    blockRow = blockIdx.x;
    blockCol = blockIdx.y;
    row = threadIdx.x;
    col = threadIdx.y;
    if (blockRow * BLOCK_SIZE + row >= n || blockCol * BLOCK_SIZE + col >= m)
        return;
    Cvalue = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        Cvalue += a[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockRow + row) * 3 + i] * b[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockCol + col) * 3 + i];
    c[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockRow + row) * m + BLOCK_SIZE * blockCol + col] = Cvalue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried also to use 2d kernel and it reduces the time to 60ms.  However, it is still very expensive. I have tried also with grid stride but still the same. The problem I see is that the kernel is not optimized and does not ensure all global reads and writes are coalesced.  I believe that using Cuda shared memory is key here if we avoid bank conflicts in shared memory.

Comment: @Arrfou You can use this example of shared memory. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory

Comment: ok, I will try to modify the code and use the shared memory. The kernel performance is really slow because the access to the resulted array c is strided  (each thread in a block is writing to a location that is an entire row away from the previous thread ) even between a and b the read and write  are not coalesced

Comment: I will not close this thread until we find the solution.

Comment: @Arrfou You can try it. but from my experience with shared memory, it doesn't always give the desired results.

Comment: ok, I want to add that  the main problem is writing results back to c. It takes about 60ms when we write c[idx]= val . I have changed  idx to int idx = i + n * j; and I got 10x faster kernel. but still the kernel is not well optimized

Comment: great, thank you. I tried it and it is  faster but even fasterif we change last line of the kernel to  c[(BLOCK_SIZE * blockRow + row)   + (BLOCK_SIZE * blockCol + col)*n] = Cvalue; If you try it please update here.

Comment: @Arrfou This will only change c from row-major to column-major. I don't think it will have much effect on performance.

Comment: Actually, it changes a lot for me like 6x faster. Now, I understand that shared memory for large arrays does not give a faster execution but only to be used with arrays where threads are cooperating which is not the case here.  p.s  I can not think of any other ways to optimize the kernel but if someone wants to use Cuda streams and have sub kernel with subarrays it will accelerate if someone encounters a similar issue in the future.  I will accept your solution as one of the helpful solutions. @AbdelAziz AbdelLatef